# Printing not working with QPrinter and a QPainter

Tags: qt

I want to print some message via my printer, but nothing happens when I compile.
What is the problem with my code?

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setCreator("Me");
printer.setDocName("Test1");

QPrintDialog *PrintConfiguration = new QPrintDialog(&printer,this);
PrintConfiguration->show();

QPainter *painter = new QPainter(&printer);
painter.drawText(10,10,ui->textEdit->toPlainText());
```

Comment: Ok, now i create relation and still nothing...                         
    QPainter *painter = new QPainter(&printer);

Answer (score 0):

The code, as presented, won't do anything since you never destruct the painter nor finish the page. You need to destruct the painter: `delete painter;`.  Alternatively, if you print multiple pages, you need to call `printer.newPage()` every time you're done with a page.

The `drawText` may very likely draw in a non-printable area of the page. Try:

```
painter->drawText(printer.pageRect(), ui->textEdit->toPlainText());
```

Comment: Kuba, thank you so much man. After 2 days executing, finally my printer device, print what i enter in the text edit. Now i need only to make my print preview and choose which information will be in it. I have no idea how to do that, but i will be searching for it. I am doing everything of this now in experimental project. I will add this to my big project. There i will select person from table view [row] from SQL database, and i will see all of this information in Print Preview dialog, then i will print it. I know it won't be easy but i have big motivation to solve that problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Look for `QPrintPreviewDialog`, read on how to use it. You'll need a `QObject` with a slot that can print out your document. Then the preview dialog will emit `paintRequested(QPrinter*)` signal, your object will simply print to that printer and it'll appear in the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here: `PrintConfiguration->show();`
`show()` preparers widget to be show and immediately returns. So result is that you are trying to paint before user managed to do any interaction with UI and you printer object is not set properly. You wanted a blocking method: `exec()`. Proper code should look  like this:

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setCreator("Me");
printer.setDocName("Test1");

QPrintDialog printDialog(printer, this);
if (printDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    QPainter painter(&printer);
    painter.drawText(10,10,ui->textEdit->toPlainText());
}
```